# Trigger is not fired multiple time in sql server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, triggers

I have a trigger on my table, it will trigger on any update of the row.

I have 10 rows in my table.

I am updating the all rows with some condition within the stored procedure.

I have seen that my trigger got triggered only once.

But i need to run the trigger for each and every update of my each row.

Can you please help me on this.

Comment: A trigger executes per statement, not per row, you get meta-tables `INSERTED` and `DELETED` containing the rows affected, you won't get the trigger to execute per row.

Answer (score 0):

In your trigger, you have a table `INSERTED` with the same schema than the triggered table in which you'll find all your 10 rows inserted/updated. You can so make batch treatment. Other way, you can iterate on this temp table to do single treatment.

Comment: But i have lot of statements and conditions with the inserted and deleted tables in the trigger. Is their any other way to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by batch treatment? We are trying to do it with the cursors to iterate by using the inserted table. But I have to modify the lot of logic here.

Comment: You can iterate on the `INSERTED` table with `CURSOR` or loops and call a stored procedure or UDF. I don't know any way to call cursor many time in one `UPDATE`. What is different between calling stored procedure 10 times or receive the trigger 10 times ?

Comment: I am calling the SP only once but i need trigger should execute 10 times.

Comment: Do a `cursor` on `INSERTED` and call the SP 10 times.

Answer (score 0):

As you are asking for 'help' on the matter, I will try and point you to a probably better direction. Your question indicates that you probably lack an important piece of knowledge about SQL. In order to remedy, you should read this:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34142/Understanding-Set-based-and-Procedural-approaches

It is all about procedural approach compared to set-based approach. Looks pretty informative to me. I'd highlight this excerpt:

> The internal execution engines of databases are designed and optimized
>   for taking "set based instructions" as input (SQL) and executing these
>   instructions in the best possible way (that varies based on a lot of
>   criteria) to produce an output. That's why "Set based approaches" are
>   almost always the better option.

That said, I believe it is not only about performance and I believe you should fix your design.

Alternatively, there are still cases for using a cursor. Could you please be more specific and give more informations about your scenario?